# compile a latex document use pdflatex ,not give a references (citation) as well as the figure numbers (ref)

Tags: reference, latex, figure, citations

I am on the process to submit a paper, and the committee need the paper in a latex form that being able to compile in pdf using one of the following compiler:
pdflatex, xelatex,lualatex or latex.

and for references using either : bibtex, biber.

I am using overleaf to generate my paper and manage the references in a form of .bib

while using the above latex generators , i got the pdf without references and figure/table citation. it gives ? instead of the exact numbers

my reference part at the end of my .tex file is as bellow :

```
\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
%\typeout{}
\bibliography{egbib}
```

I noticed that when i use the `latexmk -pdf` function in the command prompt , i got the correct pdf file with reference and citation correctly presents.

the conference need me to submit a zip file with all my document and files, and now i am not sure how to ensure that my file will regenerate correctly there.

any suggestion please ?

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 0):

To handle errors related to references not found, it is useful to compile pdflatex + bibtex + twice pdflatex again.
Alternatively, using latexmk automatically decides how many times to compile based on whether or not the pdf was successfully produced.
[Question about it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496821/latexmk-vs-pdflatex-bibtex-pdflatex-x-2)